# Syntax errors when using RegisterPowerSettingNotification

Tags: c++, winapi

I just started getting to know WINAPI after learning C++ online. I know that I should read more about WINAPI, but I want to do both learning and coding at the same time.

This is my code. Its purpose is to check a function in WINAPI, but I keep getting an error. What is wrong with my code?

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <WinUser.h>



LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
// Register the window class.
const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

WNDCLASS wc = {};

wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

RegisterClass(&wc);

// Create the window.

HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    0,                              // Optional window styles.
    CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
    L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

    // Size and position
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

    NULL,       // Parent window
    NULL,       // Menu
    hInstance,  // Instance handle
    NULL        // Additional application data
    );

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
HPOWERNOTIFY WINAPI RegisterPowerSettingNotification(_In_  HANDLE hwnd, _In_  LPCGUID GUID_LIDCLOSE_ACTION, _In_ DWORD DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);//the problem is HERE i think why is not accepting DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE if i leave it blank it works and compile but i don't get a msg 

// Run the message loop.

MSG msg = {};
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;


case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;

case WM_PAINT:
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
}
return 0;

}
return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'   c:\users\0110\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\lidclosingevent\lidclosingevent\source.cpp  48  1   LidClosingEvent
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'   c:\users\0110\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\lidclosingevent\lidclosingevent\source.cpp  48  1   LidClosingEvent
Error   3   error C2059: syntax error : ')' c:\users\0110\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\lidclosingevent\lidclosingevent\source.cpp  48  1   LidClosingEvent
    4   IntelliSense: expected a ')'    c:\Users\0110\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LidClosingEvent\LidClosingEvent\Source.cpp  48  121 LidClosingEvent
```

I use VS2013 and started with an empty project.

Comment: You have to specify any compile time or runtime errors verbatim in your question, to achieve an answer for this.

Comment: It's never good enough to say "I get an error". You have to be precise and tell us what that error is, and where it occurs.

Comment: *"I don't know how to call a function in C or C++"* is not the type of question you should be asking on SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows zero research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you copied the RegisterPowerSettingNotification function signature into your main method and changed it's parameters.

You have:

```
HPOWERNOTIFY WINAPI RegisterPowerSettingNotification(_In_  HANDLE hwnd, _In_  LPCGUID GUID_LIDCLOSE_ACTION, _In_ DWORD DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
```

When you should have:

```
RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hWnd, &GUID_LIDCLOSE_ACTION, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
```

Comment: this is the first thing that i did before here is the errors    Error 1 error C2664: 'HPOWERNOTIFY RegisterPowerSettingNotification(HANDLE,LPCGUID,DWORD)' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'const GUID' to 'LPCGUID' c:\users\0110\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\lidclosingevent\lidclosingevent\source.cpp 48 1 LidClosingEvent

Comment: 2 IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "const GUID" to "LPCGUID" exists c:\Users\0110\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\LidClosingEvent\LidClosingEvent\Source.cpp 48 41 LidClosingEvent

Comment: Change GUID_LIDCLOSE_ACTION to &GUID_LIDCLOSE_ACTION, and it should work. I will edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Worked thanks now i will go back learning more and coding more